# No module named 'keras_vggface'

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tf.keras, keras-vggface

I am trying to install 'keras_vggface' at my Jupyter notebook (running python 3.) but I am getting the following errors : [image]
[image]

```
import os, sys, requests, json
import pandas as pd

# face verification with the VGGFace2 model
import cv2

#from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine 
!pip install mtcnn
from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN
from matplotlib import pyplot

#!pip install git+https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-vggface.git
!pip install keras_applications --no-deps
!pip install keras_vggface

from keras.utils.layer_utils import get_source_inputs


#filename = "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_vggface/models.py"
#text = open(filename).read()
#open(filename, "w+").write(text.replace('keras.engine.topology', 'tensorflow.keras.utils'))
import tensorflow as tf

from keras_vggface.vggface import VGGFace
from keras_vggface.utils import preprocess_input
```

I have searched for similar questions/answers at stackoverflow but nothing worked.

My system: [image]